# Parse SQL field into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I take a SQL table that looks like this:

```
MemberNumber    JoinDate    Associate
1234            1/1/2011    A1 free A2 upgrade A31
5678            3/15/2011   A4
9012            5/10/2011   free
```

And output (using a view or writing to another table or whatever is easiest) this:

```
MemberNumber    Date
1234-P         1/1/2011
1234-A1        1/1/2011
1234-A2        1/1/2011
1234-A31       1/1/2011
5678-P         3/15/2011
5678-A4        3/15/2011
9012-P         5/10/2011
```

Where each row results in a "-P" (primary) output line as well as any A# (associate) lines.  The Associate field can contain a number of different non-"A#" values, but the "A#"s are all I'm interested in (# is from 1 to 99).  There can be many "A#"s in that one field too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this new version

```
declare @t table (MemberNumber varchar(8), JoinDate date, Associate varchar(50))  

insert into @t values  ('1234', '1/1/2011', 'A1 free A2 upgrade A31'),('5678', '3/15/2011', 'A4'),('9012', '5/10/2011', 'free')  

;with b(f, t, membernumber, joindate, associate)
as 
( 
select 1, 0, membernumber, joindate, Associate
from @t 
union all 
select t+1, charindex(' ',Associate + ' ', t+1), membernumber, joindate, Associate
from b 
where t <  len(Associate)
)
select MemberNumber + case when t = 0 then '-P' else '-'+substring(Associate, f,t-f) end NewMemberNumber, JoinDate
from b  
where t = 0 or substring(Associate, f,1) = 'A' 
--where t = 0 or substring(Associate, f,2) like 'A[1-9]' 
-- order by MemberNumber, t
```

Result is the same as the requested output.

Comment: Nice! Great to see someone else cares about performance.  I have posted an improvement to my XML approach that greatly speeds things up, but I doubt it will ever compete with a setbased query. I have also posted a numbers table approach that is twice as fast as your query. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @NathanSkerl I tuned my version to the max and achieved a slightly faster performance than yours, I admit that i now cut the same corners you did, in order to have a fair way of comparing. I am looking forward to your next improvement. I doubt i can tune mine any further. I commented out the places where the corners were cut

Comment: Excellent, ill give it a shot but I believe we've tuned enough for the OP's use case :)  Fun exercise!

Comment: Thank you @NathanSkerl and t-clausen.dk for the great lesson!

Answer (score 3):

Of course a table redesign would greatly simplify this query but sometimes we just need to get it done.  I wrote the below query using multiple CTEs; I find its easier to follow and see exactly whats going on, but you could simplify this further once you grasp the technique.

To inject your "P" primary row you will see that I simply jammed it into Associate column but it might be better placed in a simple UNION outside the CTEs.

In addition, if you do choose to refactor your schema the below technique can be used to "split" your Associate column into rows.

```
;with 
Split (MemberNumber, JoinDate, AssociateItem)
as  (       select MemberNumber, JoinDate, p.n.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(25)')
            from    (   select MemberNumber, JoinDate, n=cast('<n>'+replace(Associate + ' P',' ','</n><n>')+'</n>' as xml).query('.')
                        from @t
                    ) a
            cross apply n.nodes('n') p(n)
    )
select  MemberNumber + '-' + AssociateItem,
        JoinDate
from    Split
where   left(AssociateItem, 1) in ('A','P')
order
by      MemberNumber;
```

The XML method is not a great option performance-wise, as its speed degrades as the number of items in the "array" increases.  If you have long arrays the follow approach might be of use to you:

```
--* should be physical table, but use this cte if needed
--;with 
--number (n) 
--as    (   select top(50) row_number() over(order by number) as n
--      from    master..spt_values
--  )
    select  MemberNumber + '-' + substring(Associate, n, isnull(nullif(charindex(' ', Associate + ' P', n)-1, -1), len(Associate)) - n+1),
            JoinDate
    from    (   select MemberNumber, JoinDate, Associate + ' P' from @t
            ) t (MemberNumber, JoinDate, Associate)
    cross
    apply   number n
    where   n <= convert(int, len(Associate)) and
            substring(' ' + Associate, n, 1) = ' ' and
            left(substring(Associate, n, isnull(nullif(charindex(' ', Associate, n)-1, -1), len(Associate)) - n+1), 1) in ('A', 'P');
```

Comment: I should add that your version is faster than mine if we both include the order by. Otherwise mine is slightly faster. Interesting

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend altering your database structure by adding a link table instead of the "Associate" column. A link table would consist of two or more columns like this:

```
MemberNumber    Associate   Details
-----------------------------------
1234            A1          free
1234            A2          upgrade
1234            A31         
5678            A4
```

Then the desired result can be obtained with a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.`MemberNumber`, '-', 'P'), m.`JoinDate`
FROM `members` m
UNION
SELECT CONCAT(m.`MemberNumber`, '-', IFNULL(a.`Associate`, 'P')), m.`JoinDate`
FROM `members` m
RIGHT JOIN `members_associates` a ON m.`MemberNumber` = a.`MemberNumber`
```

Comment: Thanks - I wish I could alter the table structure, but I'm extracting the data from a crummy legacy system... thus my hands are tied.